# How to list online publications (e.g. blog posting, etc.)?

Tags: cv, outreach, blog

I am updating my CV. As for my own publications, I have the usual sections:

- Journal articles
- Book chapters
- Conference proceedings

I would also like to include the articles I have posted on different blogs.

The question is: which heading would you use for such electronic articles? They are not really conventional, peer-reviewed articles, so frankly I don't see fair to include them under the "Journal articles" section.

I saw some people use "Other publications", but I would like to be more specific.

Comment: See also: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/can-something-published-on-arxiv-or-optimization-online-org-be-mentioned-in-my-c?newreg=a5f0ba18ae3d47e98cee73b0ac1f7ea9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep it under a relevant label to make it sure that you don't pretend to have more peer-reviewed publications.

E.g. *"Blog posts"*, or as I do: *"Popular science and education-related articles (selected)"*.

If there are many, be sure to select only the most important/relevant ones.

Comment: I have a section called "Other public output". (And  my articles section is "Peer Reviewed Articles.")