# Does Arxiv count as publication?

Tags: publications, cv, research-undergraduate, arxiv

I am an undergraduate student graduating next month. I wrote a research paper done by myself, but it's been rejected by two journals sofar so I haven't been able to publish it.

I am applying for scholarships and  having a published paper would improve my chances.

If i upload my paper in arxiv, is it considered as published paper? can i write it in my cv as published paper and what is the most suitable way to write it *in my cv?

Thank you!

Comment: Someone already gave an answer, but let me mention something. When you put something on arXiv, they will never remove it (unless in some exceptional circumstances such as copyright infringement, or if you upload something which is a not a research paper at all). If your paper has such issues that it has been rejected twice, you may want to be careful before making it public.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi then should i just let it and take it to bookshelf for ever? Is there any place to put "a rejected paper" or a place to collect a bunch of rejected paper?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if the paper has been rejected *twice* you need to know why before you decide if you want to make it part of a permanent public archive. If you have not gotten useful feedback from the journals then you probably want to find your own reviewer—a person with solid domain knowledge who and experience in writing published papers but not affiliated with the work who would be willing to read it and give you an honest enumeration of it's weaknesses.

Answer (score 10):

No, it's not considered a published paper in the usual sense of *peer-reviewed publications*. ArXiv is meant as a preprint server where you upload preprint versions (essentially polished draft versions) to quickly disseminate your research, before submitting it to a scholarly journal where the paper undergoes peer review. Only after the paper has been peer-reviewed and published by the journal do you have a "real" publication. (Depending on your agreement with the journal, it's then possible to update the arXiv listing to reflect revisions made to the manuscript during the publication process.)

It's still appropriate to list such preprints on your CV - especially early on in a career, when you might have few peer-reviewed publications. [This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/can-something-published-on-arxiv-or-optimization-online-org-be-mentioned-in-my-c) is fine as long as it's made clear that these are preprints, or manuscripts under review or similar.

Comment: This. It goes on you "List of Publications", but you don't refer to the paper as "published".

Answer (score 6):

I would say it **does** count as a publication if you need to reference it in your own work/papers. So if you publish a result you can reference this ArXiV paper.

However, it does **not** count as a peer-review publication in the sense that it does not "add" points/credit to your cv.