# Does arXiv do peer review and can a high school student submit to arXiv?

Tags: preprint

1. Is it necessary to publish in a journal after writing paper in arXiv?
2. Is arXiv peer reviewed journal? If yes, then will the editor
   consider and send to other experts in that field?
3. Can a high school student publish paper in arXiv? If not is there any other way a high school student can share scientific knowledge (only if they have discovered something new)?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/can-something-published-on-arxiv-or-optimization-online-org-be-mentioned-in-my-c

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115825/does-arxiv-count-as-publication

Comment: https://arxiv.org/about

Comment: Thank you Jet Chung, for the papers of your friends. I have a doubt that is, the second paper (arxiv.org/abs/2009.00708) has no endorsement and how it got agreed by arxiv.

Comment: And also is there any need of PhD qualification to publish in arxiv. I mean during registration as an author they ask us info about university, what should a high school student at that point.

Comment: Getting a paper into arXiv should not be called "publishing".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(1) There's no requirement that you have to publish in a journal after putting a paper on arXiv. However, in my experience, most people who put something on arXiv do also submit it to a journal, although this depends on which field of science you are talking about.

(2) Arxiv is not a peer-reviewed journal, there are no editors or referees. This is why a lot of people submit to both arXiv and a journal.

(3) Probably not by themselves, but they could if they can convince an established researcher to endorse them.

Unless the student was already affiliated with a known university or research institute, they would usually have to get an "endorsement" to be able to submit. An "endorsement" means that an established researcher confirms that the paper being submitted is appropriate for an arXiv submission and that the authors have some idea what they are talking about.

If the student knows any researchers in the field they want to publish a paper in, they could ask them to have a look at their paper and give some feedback. If they agree that the paper is above a minimum standard they might agree to endorse.

If the student does not know any researchers, it is more difficult. They could find out who the experts in the field are and email them directly, in a polite manner, but should be aware that out-of-the-blue requests from someone unheard of are likely to be ignored.

There's more information about how endorsements work here: https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement

There may not be any shortcut to this. The best option might be for the student to wait, apply to study the field that interests them at university, and after learning more about the subject and getting to know some professors there, ask them if they'd be willing to look at their research. If they thought it was good, they would be able to endorse the student for submission to arXiv and give advice about the publication process in general.

Comment: They might be able to get an endorsement if one of the teachers at their school got an account there while doing a post-grad degree.

Comment: @nick012000 I would expect that most high school teachers don't ever do a research-oriented post-grad degree and would not have an arxiv account. I.e. that it's *possible* that one of their teachers would have an account, but that would be a rare coincidence.

Comment: @Peteris: I don't know which country the OP is in, but in the U.S. high school teachers typically have to take continuing education/certification courses during the summers, and these enrollments might provide a year-round .edu email address. Also, many teachers will be working on Masters degrees over a period of several years. In fact, in New York (the state) teachers must earn a Masters degree within 5 years of beginning teaching in New York in order to remain licensed to teach in New York (see "Step 7" at [this web page](https://www.teacher.org/state/new-york/)).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, yes, "continuing education", but most of that (in my own observation, and from understanding requirements) is not in the subject matter (e.g., math), but in "education". In particular, there'll rarely be contact with _mathematicians_, as opposed to math educators... which will not be the right set-up to get an endorsement for arXiv, I think. Could be wrong!

Comment: Although not peer-reviewed submissions are nevertheless moderated: “ Submissions to arXiv are subject to a moderation process that classifies material as topical to the subject area and has scholarly value.”  This keeps crank submissions out of the site.  Note also that only “Registered users may submit articles to be announced by arXiv”; I have no experience as to the requirements to become registered if you are a high school student.

Comment: @nick An account is not enough to provide an endorsement. It requires a certain number of papers on arXiv in the category one wishes to endorse for.

Comment: Thank you all for massive response for my question

Comment: @paul garrett: After reading your comment just now, I realized that I confused "student having an .edu address" with "teacher having an .edu address". The teacher can use the .edu address to post at arXiv, but unless the teacher actually does so (which I agree is extremely unlikely), the teacher cannot endorse the student.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero [Here's a story to add to that.](https://backreaction.blogspot.com/2016/01/does-arxiv-censor-submissions.html) Yes, submissions may be rejected by moderators.

Answer (score 35):

A high school student (with an endorsement as twestley laid out nicely) can publish on the arxiv, but very likely a high school student should not do this.

In my field, the arxiv is read daily by everyone in the field. There is no peer-review process, but we do self censor quite a bit. We usually circulate our research through our networks and get feedback before posting. Putting something on the arxiv that is low quality has serious impacts on your career. Your name is attached to that forever, and afaik you can't take it down and erase its history. Plus you can't undo anything to the wide audience that will see it the first day it gets posted.

In some sense, posting on the arxiv is more dangerous than going through peer-reviewed channels. If you submit something embarrassing to a journal, they won't publish it. The arxiv has no such safeguard.

Unless you know someone who you think can serve the purpose of a peer reviewer, and who can give an informed approval that your work won't be rejected by the community and reflect poorly on you, I strongly suggest you do NOT post to the arxiv. It could hurt you professionally if you end up in an arxiv-popular field. If you end up in an arxiv-unpopular field, then posting wouldn't really benefit you much either (as it's not a real journal). It's just not a good gamble.

Comment: Very good points! The people who decry a loss of "peer review" often seem to overlook both the self-censorship and the risks of too-hasty publication-to-the-world, regardless of whether it's "traditional publication".

Comment: Rings especially true because of the OP's previous statement that their research is "related to million dollar prize problems" (posted yesterday: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/156363/will-arxiv-accept-papers-without-university-affiliation). It might benefit them to read Henry Cohn's short page of advice: http://math.mit.edu/~cohn/Thoughts/advice.html

Comment: In cause you're curious (as I was), the author of this answer works in theoretical physics (from their [user page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/129384/well))

Answer (score 2):

It is not too hard to submit to the arxiv. It won't be difficult to get "endorsement" if that is still a requirement. I actually thought that was gotten rid of.

Once you are done your PhD, if you do decide to do that, the arxiv preprint will be so old that it certainly will not have much impact one way or another. If some idea in it still interests you then, you will have the option to reference the arxiv preprint (wording like "as we showed in [3].") If you don't do that, I highly doubt that anyone will notice this old preprint. Certainly, for example, a hiring committee is not likely to dig up an old preprint, and check that is is really the same person.

Comment: I always look up the full bibliography of people I'm considering collaborating with. There are search engines like Inspire that link to the arxiv and this paper will appear in the front page of the author's name until many more publications are accumulated. My guess is it would easily haunt them through a PhD and into the postdoc search.

Comment: *I actually thought that was gotten rid of* --- It's the other way around. In the 1990s and early 2000s, an endorsement was not needed, but then the requirement was put into place. Naturally, Murphy's law applied to me, and when an endorsement wasn't needed, I was teaching and had an .edu address (so I never worried about one day getting some of my unpublished work put there for others, so I just continued to tweak the manuscripts at my leisure), but about the same time the requirement was established, I no longer had an .edu email.

Answer (score 1):

1. Publication on ArXiv is not considered as a formal publication, as it has not been peer reviewed.  A few journals ask you to submit to ArXiv first before submitting to the journal, although this isn't very common.
2. Arxiv is not peer reviewed, there is a barrier which a submission has to surpass in order to be accepted as an Arxiv submission but I'm not sure how high it is.  Bear in mind that once you submit something to Arxiv you need a reason to withdraw it and you can only withdraw the PDF file, everything else will remain on Arxiv.
3. I don't know, perhaps you could submit to Arxiv as an independent researcher.  Otherwise, the easiest thing would probably be to somehow convince a researcher at a university that you have something publishable, then polish it together and submit it as a joint publication.