# In CV, how to mention articles published only in arxiv?

Tags: publications, cv, arxiv

In the publications section of the CV, what is the best title for articles that have not yet been published in a peer-reviewed conference or journal and have only been published in the [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org) ?

How about "**near future publications**" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can something published on arXiv or optimization-online.org be mentioned in my CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/can-something-published-on-arxiv-or-optimization-online-org-be-mentioned-in-my-c)

Comment: @Sursulasupportsthestrike , My question is not whether arXiv can be mentioned in CV because I believe it can be. My question was how to mention it. And I got the answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The official word used by NIH is "Preprints".  I believe this is the correct industry term.  Some links for more information:

- [NIH](https://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/2023/02/08/nih-preprint-pilot-expands-to-include-preprints-across-nih-funded-research/)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprint)

Comment: Scopus uses this term too

Answer (score 28):

**Accepted but not yet published:** accepted, forthcoming, to appear, in press

**Under review but not yet accepted:** under review, submitted to [journal/conference]

**Not yet submitted:** manuscript, preprint

**Not even finished yet:** work in progress

The term "near future publications" would only be appropriate for the category of accepted but not yet published work, but even there it sounds strange and unidiomatic. I have never seen anyone use this term before, and there are many better alternatives.

For any other category it is simply not appropriate at all because you do not in fact know whether your submission will be accepted or not. It would be like listing "near future jobs" on your CV simply because you are convinced that you will definitely ace the job interview.

Comment: Another common term for accepted but not yet published is _in press_.

Comment: I'm not a fan of ''Under review'', I feel like people use it to their advantage by submitting to a certain journal and then put it down as ''Under review at X'' when applying for a job knowing that there is a very good chance they will be rejected by that journal.

Comment: @Tom I also dislike specifying *where* it's under review, but the fact that it is under review is still useful information IMO. If it's just a "preprint" it may not be intended for publication at all.

Comment: In addition to @Tom's concern, I'd also note that I'm not a big fan of listing "work in progress" on a CV. From my experience in maths, it's not so unlikely that an article which is currently "work in progress" will still be so one or two years ahead (even if it seems right now like you're certainly going to submit it within two months because, you know, right after the current teaching period ends you'll finally have enough time to complete it...)

Comment: @JochenGlueck yeah, maths research is definitely subject to [Hofstadter's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law).

Comment: If you want to have your paper 'under review', but it's actually not done you can always submit to the Journal of Universal Rejection https://www.universalrejection.org/

Comment: @AlexbGoode The journal seems to be defunct.  They seem not to have published an issue since 2013. :P

Comment: There also needs to be a way of saying that it has been uploaded with no intention of sending it to a journal (in my case because I have no way of paying open access fees and there is no academic point, at least in the UK, in my publishing it if it isn't open access).  Peer review is the first step to acceptance by the research community, not the last, and it isn't the only route.  In the end the quality and correctness of the idea is all that ought to be important.  Citation count is also a quality indicator, so no problem in putting highly cited ArXiV papers on CV.

Comment: @user71659 Added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Simply write your paper and add an arXiv preprint with the URL there. Here is an example:

Kevin Du, Lucas Torroba Hennigen, Niklas Stoehr, Alexander Warstadt, Ryan Cotterell
"Generalizing Backpropagation for Gradient-Based Interpretability" arXiv preprint, https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.03056

Answer (score 5):

If your intention is that they are preprints intended for later formal publication, I'd list them as "Work in Progress".

Another alternative is to list them as "Unreviewed Publications", though I'm not sure I recommend that. But it is accurate if you consider them finished and don't intend to submit them to a publisher/conference.

The former is a definite plus if you are seeking employment. The latter may have issues.

In a "Work in Progress" section you could mark those that are "nearing submission" as such. But it is (IMO) useful to also have some projects there that are in their earlier stages.

Comment: How about "**near future publications**" ?

Comment: If they are under review you could use that as a heading, but otherwise it is a bit tentative. Work in Progress implies continuing activity, which is a plus, I think. That is the impression you want to give a potential employer.

Comment: If the manuscript is complete and posted to arXiv (or some other preprint server), I would not call it a "work in progress".  If I see "work in progress" on a CV, I am going to assume that the paper is not written yet, or even that the basic research has not yet been completed.  I think that the standard term is "preprint" (this connotes a completed work which has not yet been submitted for publication).

Comment: I've never seen ''near future publications'' and would consider it strange if I saw it on a CV.

Comment: I don't think there is really a need to label them as "Unreviewed Publications" if they are on ArXiv.  Might be a good idea to include citations (or link to the Google scholar page where the citations can be found).  I'd say an "unreviewed publication" that others had built on is better than a relatively uncited but peer reviewed paper that the research community has essentially ignored.